# Dual 4k monitors - only one works at full resolution and refresh rate at a time

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display, display-resolution

just got a new setup at work which consist of a Lenovo thinkpad P1 Gen6 with a Geforce RTX 4600 and a [thinkpad thunderbolt 4 docking station](https://support.lenovo.com/dk/da/solutions/pd500533-thinkpad-thunderbolt-4-workstation-dock-overview-and-service-parts) with 2 1.4 display ports. To go along with this setup I have 2 LG27UL650 monitors. The problem is that ubuntu seems unable to display both these monitors when both are running in full resolution at 60 Hz. Ubuntu detects both monitors, but cannot show the second monitor unless I lower the resolution to 2560*1440 or the refresh rate to 30 Hz.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

My question is similar to the question here: [Dual 4k monitors - only one works at a time though both are discoverable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373197/dual-4k-monitors-only-one-works-at-a-time-though-both-are-discoverable)
But in my case the ports in the docking station should support the resolution/refresh rate I want and the computer should as well.

I am currently connecting using the 2 display ports.

```
alex5971@internalit-ThinkPad-P1-Gen-6:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 7680 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1600    165.00 +  60.00 +  60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x768i     60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   832x624       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   720x400       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x400       60.00  
   576x432       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   640x350       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x384i      60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   416x312       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   360x200       60.00  
   320x200       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
   320x175       60.00  
DP-1-3.1.6 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3.2 connected 3840x2160+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  30.00* 
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

Does anyone have any good suggestions for how I can fix this issue?